# Adding methods gives a 'index out of range error'?

Tags: python, html, post, flask, sqlite

When adding a vital component of `methods=["POST", "GET"]`, my code gives the error:

`Line 127, in PatientDashboard
""".format(Data[0][0]))
IndexError: list index out of range`

I understand what this error normally means but I don't understand how adding methods affect the size of my list.

```
@app.route("/PatientDashboard.html", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def PatientDashboard():
    Username = (request.args.get("Username"))

    Connection = sqlite3.connect(DB)
    Cursor = Connection.cursor()
    Data = Cursor.execute("""
        SELECT *
        FROM PatientTable
        WHERE Username = '{}'
    """.format(Username))
    Data = Data.fetchall()

    AllAppointments = Cursor.execute("""
        SELECT Title, Firstname, Surname, TimeSlot, Date, Status
        FROM AppointmentTable
        INNER JOIN DoctorTable ON AppointmentTable.DoctorID = DoctorTable.DoctorID
        WHERE PatientID = '{}'
    """.format(Data[0][0]))
    AllAppointments = AllAppointments.fetchall()
```

The SQL statements work perfectly (database isn't empty) and when adding `print(Data)` after the first SQL statement there is an output of a nested list.

I have tried troubleshooting by looking at various other questions on stackoverflow but with no luck.

Thank you ever so much in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

```
Username = (request.args.get("Username"))
print("Username: ", Username)
```

Gives the correct output, e.g. `Username: nx_prv` but after using the POST request the output becomes `Username: None`.

**EDIT 2:**

I have managed to fix this using `flask.sessions`. The problem was that the `request.args.get("Username")` was getting 'reset' every time.

Comment: Could you also paste the `Data` before the `format` call and show us ?

Comment: That's the likely result of a POST (since `request.args.get....`) will be None)

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus please could you expand on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario I envision: the route was tested with a GET method (because there was not `methods` argument), and everything was fine. The `methods` argument was added so a POST could be tested, and it "stopped working". But it really didn't stop working, it's just not built to handle a POST request.

From [flask doc on request object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data) the two salient attributes are:

> **form**
>
> A MultiDict with the parsed form data from POST or PUT requests. Please keep in mind that file uploads will not end up here, but
>   instead in the files attribute.
>
> **args**
>
> A MultiDict with the parsed contents of the query string. (The part in the URL after the question mark).

So a GET request will "populate" `args` and a POST request, `form`.  Username will be `None` from this line `Username = (request.args.get("Username"))` on a POST request.

You can determine which method by interrogating the method attribute of the request object.

> **method**
>
> The current request method (POST, GET etc.)